# Instagram, get JSON feed for cetain hashtag without using API

Tags: json, instagram-api, feed

I am creating a personal app and I am having some trouble. I have tried using the Instagram API to get a JSON feed of images by hashtag (any image insta, not just images on my profile).

My issue with the API is that i cannot seem to search public images without having my app in live mode. i keep getting a 400 unauthorized access_token error, even though i do have a valid access token.

I cannot put my app in live mode because insta require a privacy policy url and a company name and I am not a company. I am an independent dev making a personal app.

Whilst searching through stack overflow i cam across this url:

https://www.instagram.com/bikerpicgirl/media/

This allows me to get images by user without the API. I am wondering if anyone knows a similar url where i can get a feed like this but for hashtags instead of users.

I could just make a scraper that mimics the search process but this seems way to overkill and is alot of effort for something that should be so simple.

Comment: i wish, but there is none available for hashtag

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542335/how-to-get-all-images-of-hashtag-in-instagram-without-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can explore `Instagram` media by `hashtags` with this `url` format:

```
/explore/tags/your-tag/
```

for example if `hashtag` is `#amsterdam` your `url` would look something like this:

https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/amsterdam/

As Jon Goodwin mentioned in the comment this  [example link](https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/amsterdam/)  is subject to change and may not work in the future.

Comment: Thanks @SergejV ,as you know this is a *user moderated site* that comment  is a *standard text*  (from clicking a *radio button* for *link only answer* you can tell it it not a normal comment because it says `From Review` before my name). It's part of the process of being a good citizen of the site, I hope you too will take the opportunity to help with *review* also in the future (as you gain more rep).  I edited your answer because I thought you were confused, and and it put your answer in a worse light than was merited. Hopefully things are more clear now. Keep up the good work !