# How to get all images of hashtag in Instagram without API?

Tags: php, instagram

This is the code that I used to get images of hashtag without API. I do not want to use any credentials. It does not require me to add either `client_id` or access token. But I only get 15 images. How can I get all the images?

```
 <div>

    <form action='#' method='post'>
    <input type='input' name='txttag' />
    <input type='submit' value='Get Image' />
    </form>

    </div>


    <?php 
    function scrape_insta_hash($tag) {
        $insta_source = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'.$tag.'/'); // instagrame tag url
        $shards = explode('window._sharedData = ', $insta_source);
        $insta_json = explode(';</script>', $shards[1]); 
        $insta_array = json_decode($insta_json[0], TRUE);
        return $insta_array; // this return a lot things print it and see what else you need
    }

    if(isset($_POST['txttag']))
    {
        $tag =$_POST['txttag']; // tag for which ou want images 
        $results_array = scrape_insta_hash($tag);
        $limit = 15; // provide the limit thats important because one page only give some images then load more have to be clicked
        $image_array= array(); // array to store images.
            for ($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++) { 
                $latest_array = $results_array['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]['tag']['media']['nodes'][$i];
                $image_data  = '<img src="'.$latest_array['thumbnail_src'].'">'; // thumbnail and same sizes 
                //$image_data  = '<img src="'.$latest_array['display_src'].'">'; actual image and different sizes 
                array_push($image_array, $image_data);
            }
            foreach ($image_array as $image) {
                echo $image;// this will echo the images wrap it in div or ul li what ever html structure 
            }
            //https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/your-tag-name/
    }
    ?>



    <style>
    img {
      height: 200px;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Great this is still working thank you

Answer (score 50):

Easily way is request with `?__a=1` like `https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/girls/?__a=1` and receive JSON without parsing HTML and `window._sharedData =`

In json you can see *page_info* scope with *end_cursor*:

```
"page_info": {
    "has_previous_page": false,
    "start_cursor": "1381007800712523480",
    "end_cursor": "J0HWCVx1AAAAF0HWCVxxQAAAFiYA",
    "has_next_page": true
},
```

use *end_cursor* to request next portion of images:

`https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/girls/?__a=1&max_id=J0HWCVx1AAAAF0HWCVxxQAAAFiYA`

UPD:

```
<?php

$baseUrl = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/girls/?__a=1';
$url = $baseUrl;

while(1) {
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    print_r($json->tag->media->nodes);
    if(!$json->tag->media->page_info->has_next_page) break;
    $url = $baseUrl.'&max_id='.$json->tag->media->page_info->end_cursor;
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to print more than 20 images with your code.

Comment: i not get the url for vedio. can you help?

Comment: did you know how to get vedio?

Comment: @jigsparmar you need to request each video post by shortcode like ``https://www.instagram.com/p/BM39M3XBz-F/?__a=1`` (change ``BM39M3Xbz-F`` to shortcode of post you want and you will receive json with video url)

Comment: Works brilliant! I never heard about the `?__a=1` tag. For others who are looking to understand how to extract info from JSON data, have a look at this guy's article: `http://www.picssel.com/build-a-simple-instagram-api-case-study/`

Comment: Any ideas how to get JSON (or other format of data) for list of Followers and Following?

Comment: Let's hope that Instagram doesn't notice this for a while…

Comment: @ilyapt how did you know this method? It's awesome! Would you point us to the documentation link?

Comment: @Emkey instagram's official site uses this method for ajax requests. There are a lot of interesting requests for scraping instagram data. I just saw how to work that site with chrome developer tools.

Comment: @ilyapt would you teach us where exactly it can be seen in the developer tools?

Comment: how can I get posts using various hashtags in my android app?

Comment: `caption: "..."
code: "..."
comments: Object { count: 0 }
comments_disabled: false
date: 1510945307
dimensions: Object { height: 1080, width: 1080 }
display_src: "https://..."
is_video: false
likes: Object { count: 31 }
owner: Object { id: "123456789" }`

..any idea how to get the "owner name" by ID?

Comment: @BenCoffin, yes, I know how to get it, but this is not easy way.

First you do request to:
```https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17888483320059182&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%22_put_owner_id_here_%22%2C%22first%22%3A12%7D```

just replace _put_owner_id_here_ to "owner id" you want and you receive 12 posts posted this user, then make request with any post shortcode, like

```https://www.instagram.com/p/_put_post_shortcode_here_/?__a=1```

replace _put_post_shortcode_here_ to shortcode from 1st step and check in received json owner object contains "owner username"

Comment: &max_id= does not work on https://www.instagram.com/salehmosleh/?__a=1&max_id=1569828694092266307 .

Comment: i never comment just for thanks, but man thanks. 1 upvote is not enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

The Answer from Legionar was great but it is not working anymore. I had to update the code in my working Environment here is how it works for me:

```
function scrape_insta_hash($tag) {
  $insta_source = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'.$tag.'/'); // instagrame tag url
  $shards = explode('window._sharedData = ', $insta_source);
  $insta_json = explode(';</script>', $shards[1]);
  $insta_array = json_decode($insta_json[0], TRUE);
  return $insta_array; // this return a lot things print it and see what else you need
}

$tag = "my_hashtag";
$results_array = scrape_insta_hash($tag);

$limit = 18; // provide the limit thats important because one page only give some images then load more have to be clicked

for ($i=$limit; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  if(array_key_exists($i,$results_array['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]["graphql"]["hashtag"]["edge_hashtag_to_media"]["edges"])){
    $latest_array = $results_array['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]["graphql"]["hashtag"]["edge_hashtag_to_media"]["edges"][$i]["node"];

      $newPosting = [
        "image"=>$latest_array['display_url'],
        "thumbnail"=>$latest_array['thumbnail_src'],
        "instagram_id"=>$latest_array['id'],
        "caption"=>$latest_array['caption']['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]["node"]["text"],
        "link"=>"https://www.instagram.com/p/".$latest_array['shortcode'],
        "date"=>$latest_array['taken_at_timestamp']
      ];

      echo "<pre>"; 
      print_r($newPosting); 
      echo "/<pre>"; 

  }
}
```

You may need to change the "newPosting" array depending on what you need but at least for now you can get the instagram data with this method. Also there is more data inside $latest_array . Different image-sizes, comments and likes for example.

Comment: Can you expand a little bit more on $limit variable? Are you using it to limit the calls to the instagram servers?

Comment: Hey the $limit variable in this case does nothing important. We do one request  when calling: file_get_contents("..."), than we transform the result into an array we can work with. 

Then we just go over the array until the "limit" is reached. I dont know how many posts are usually stored in such a request but normaly you want to show like the latest 15 images or so...

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me perfectly.

I only needed the thumbnails. You can easily change it to full size image.
This example does not solve pagination, but you can do that from @ilyapt answer.

```
$tag = 'coronavirus';
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/$tag/?__a=1", true));

$i = 0;
foreach($json->graphql->hashtag->edge_hashtag_to_media->edges as $key => $value) {
    $img = $value->node->thumbnail_resources[0]->src;
    echo "<img src='$img'>";
    if (++$i == 9) break; // limit to the 9 newest posts
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as of '20. Literally laughed at the tag choice.

Answer (score 0):

@olaf answer worked great for me!

@Tomas The limit is the number of posts that will be returned by the function so that it doesn't return all of them.

Also: this function puts the Instagram posts in order from oldest to newest.  If you want the latest to be first and go backwards to the limit number:

Change

```
for ($i=$limit; $i >= 0; $i--)
```

to

```
for ($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++)
```