# How is next cursor in this Instagram json response encoded

Tags: graphql, instagram, relay

When appending `?__a=1` to a page on Instagram it is possible to view the JSON, as in this link:

https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/malta/?__a=1.

This response contains an `end_cursor` field that references the last object in the response. The format of this field is: `"J0HWJ-mOAAAAF0HWJ-hGgAAAFiYA`.

Does anyone have a clue on how I can find out what information was encoded inside the string?

Comment: Refer to this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542335/how-to-get-all-images-of-hashtag-in-instagram-without-api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542335/how-to-get-all-images-of-hashtag-in-instagram-without-api)

Comment: I know where to find it and it's an encoded string of some of the info in the response. I want to know what information.

Comment: That is probably a cookie or a database cursor marker; an info only relevant to Instagram. I'm not sure how that would be of any use to you.