# Get all user medias - Instagram

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I can get Instagram photos via public API with the code below (as seen in [How to get all images of hashtag in Instagram without API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542335/how-to-get-all-images-of-hashtag-in-instagram-without-api))

```
<?php

$baseUrl = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/girls/?__a=1';
$url = $baseUrl;

while(1) {
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    print_r($json->tag->media->nodes);
    if(!$json->tag->media->page_info->has_next_page) break;
    $url = $baseUrl.'&max_id='.$json->tag->media->page_info->end_cursor;
}
```

However, this code is returned to me only 95 medias, even the user has 1000+ medias (any user)

There is something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The cost of overhead in sending literally all media to you would be not worth it for instagram.  I think 95 should be plenty, but there should be a way of paging through it.  Do you know how he got that link, I've never seen it before.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel: https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper

Comment: Hmm... I'll take a look. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use [instagram-php-scraper](https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper)?

You can install it via `composer`.   Create a new dir on your server and type the following on your console:

```
composer require raiym/instagram-php-scraper
```

Then simply use:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use InstagramScraper\Instagram;
$medias = Instagram::getMediasByTag('pedro', 200);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($medias);
```

---

Check all the available methods:

https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks :)